Time for site logo?
This was the main proposal, refined and agreed on by all voices here from our site's community.
An alternative is listed as an answer from the OP, but that alternative may not be preferable.

It has been over 12 years since Hermeneutics started. The first Meta question was how this site can distinguish itself from Christianity. One way is with a logo. With how much we have grown, it may be time.
The logo must be decided by the community; that's you!
I took about three hours this morning to draft up this, merely as a first suggestion to get the ball rolling. If anyone wants to make a big improvement or everyone heavily votes for another, bravo!
I ran the first draft by our other moderators in chat, got feedback, and have come back with this.
For your consideration
Headline (for top of main site)

Logo (to appear under 64 pixels wide)



Example Appearances
These are mock-ups of the logo pasted in, but it gives us a general idea








Site colors
We will need some CSS colors, but to keep things simple, the EL&U site agrees with this logo's colors quite well. So, if we used their colors, but made our flair into our darker brown (HTML #926A32) rather than their maroon, then side by site, the sites would look something like this...
EL&U (current)

BH inherited CSS, with dark brown flair #926A32 (proposed)

Reference
Full Artwork
250

128

64

32

16

Simple Artwork
250

128

64

32

16


Considerations
Here are some comments about this design, from the work and from the mod chat...

It took a lot of time to balance the lines, thicknesses, and spacing.
Aleph is the first letter, which is the first letter of the Hebrew alephbet.
Omega is the second letter, which is the last letter of the Greek alphabet.
There could be concern about being "Christian", which we are not, because of the two letters,

but these are letters of the manuscripts that we are here to study: Hebrew and Greek.


The first letter is Hebrew and the second is Greek, relating to Old Testament and New Testament respective languages.
Searching "hermeneutics" in Google Images returns many photos of a magnifying glass being held to a Greek or Hebrew manuscript.
The magnifying glass must be used in a way that communicates "study of [what we study]" and is not confused with "search results"; this achieves that goal.
The icon must be usable against both light and dark backgrounds.
The lines and colors must not muddle the image at different sizes.
The arrangement of the letters must reflect some thought and art; these include a calligraphy from Hebrew and a Roman style from Greek—fitting for their respective times.
The design must be clear, explanatory, but not distracting.
It must be not difficult to look at.
It must be clearly unique and distinguishable from the plethora of other logos and icons on the web.
It must explain the essence of our site so that it helps visitors understand who we are and what we do.

Site-wide icon/logo vs home site heading...

For smaller renders, the designed logo could not be recognized, so a simple version was made, which can be recognized most places where it would appear, usually about 50 pixels wide or smaller.
If that simple icon is used for the larger artwork at the top of the site, then it is difficult to understand or interpret.
The font used for the home site heading had some considerations...

It is a simple, quasi-script decorative, similar to the Blackletter font of the time of the printing press and European Reformations, the only and first font used before Nicolas Jenson invented the first Roman font.
That same time was about when John Calvin pioneered the manner of objective hermeneutics we so often discuss on this site. (Even from Luther and before, no hermeneutics were used in understanding Bible that would even be remotely recognizable to what we discuss on this site.)
So, a font that resembles a good handwriting version from the first Gutenberg printing press Blackletter font of that era (and which much of our earliest relevant hermeneutics-based literature may often include) is fitting, not only in first impressions, but also historically.



These thoughts went into careful consideration in designing this. So...

What say you?

Can we accept this logo?
Does anyone have any other design to suggest?
Is it okay to finally get a logo for our site and finalize our phase out of beta?


I like the design a lot. BUT... If we are limited to the 16 pt size on the "all sites" page then we need something simpler, perhaps just the scroll without the magnifying glass and letters.  If we can use the 32 pt size I'm all for it.

@DanFefferman I agree and have already been contemplating a 16-32 size logo version and hope to push one out inside this soon.

@Jesse wow, you guys did a lot.  Love the mock ups; the smaller simplified version looks great in them.

@GratefulDisciple Frankly, I did all the work and it was my idea; much gratitude to the other two mods for letting my reigns loose, but with feedback, so I could get it done quicker. I just love you all and wanted a gift of self-dignity for us all on this 12+ year site, something everyone would feel explained by.

My big concern is that we see reason for a more artful design on the main heading from the simple logo/icon everywhere else. Every other SE site I can find has the same logo in their header as the icon, but that just wouldn't work here. Our header's artwork needs more detail to explain what that simple logo/icon means.

@Jesse Thank you, Jesse for singlehandedly creating this gift for us.  Much appreciated.  I agree that 2 versions of the logo is necessary for BH.SE.

Let's pull the trigger and go with Jesse's proposal.

FYI there was some informal and mostly joking discussion from other site moderators about how the Hebrew and Greek letters look like English for the small icon. But, it was determined that it will look like English no matter which Hebrew and Greek letters we choose, and this did not need to be addressed anyway, even from the beginning of that discussion. So, it may resemble English, but that is inevitable. Other ideas came up, but all were addressed on this post and have unanimous support from the opinions voiced here from our site's community.

One last note: I have .svg files of these logos available, just waiting to know where to send them.

I love the amount of work that went into putting this together. Unfortunately, site customization request resources are essentially non-existent at the moment. I will put this on a backlog to revisit for our next go around on site customizations. So for the time being this will need to be status-deferred.

@SpencerG thank you for the acknowledgement. When you're ready, we have a logo picked out.

Without reading the entire post and just by looking at the logo, I like it a lot already.  The meaning that pops up to me without reading the entire post are these 4 elements:

scroll symbolizing original manuscript,
the Hebrew aleph and the Greek omega letters to denote the main 2 languages, the A-Z symbolizing the whole Bible, and
the magnifying glass symbolizing painstaking examination / study.

Naturally: I vote to accept!  One suggestion: The question body might want to show in which places the logo will appear, with mockups even better.  Some high traffic pages:

Inbox (16px)


Network profile (16px)


Site-wide icon (16px, used in browser tab)


Chat homepage (16px)


All sites (28px, 70px when a site has heavier traffic, and 100px)





So it seems the 16px version is the most important, so we do want to get it right.
And yes, please take this site out of beta.  I was wondering why this site is out of alignment with the rest, having been in beta for the longest time.
Thanks a ton for doing the pre-work on making a logo that suits the design requirement.  How about adding a picture for the 404 page as well?

Thank you! I have added a simple design for the smaller sizes.

"And yes, please take this site out of beta. I was wondering why this site is out of alignment with the rest, having been in beta for the longest time." just a note that this site has graduated since 2019. The site design is a different matter since it requires designers from SE, and some sites got it after more than 6 years.

It is good. In fact, it might even be very good!
To be clear, this logo would appear where the current "BH" appears in graphic I pasted in below? With the 16 pt version you can't really distinguish the magnifying glass (or anything else) without a magnifying glass! This defeats the purpose of a logo. If we can use the 32 pt version on the "all sites" s.e. page then I vote yes. If not, we may need a something simpler.

Here's the current Christianity.se logo

I'd add that different background color than the default light blue would also help draw people's eyes to our logo.

Good point there. Added a suggestion in my answer.

Thank you, I've added a simple design variant for smaller renders.

Reversed the Hebrew aleph and Greek omega
After some discussion, it seems that the aleph and omega appear like the word "NO" in smaller logo renders.
No matter what Hebrew and Greek letters we use, it may appear like an English word to English speakers. This cannot be avoided.
But, this is an attempt to soften that first impression by placing the aleph lower and the omega raised after, reverse from the proposal in the question.
Also, in these renders, the aleph-omega is slightly larger; this could be scaled down slightly also.
The primary issue is that this alternative might not be as visually balanced, or that might not be an issue at all.
This is not necessarily better, but it is an alternative consideration.
Headline (for top of main site)

Logo (to appear under 64 pixels wide)



Example Appearances











I hope we can also consider an updated site description. I made a suggestion here
It seems to me we should make a distinction between questions (which anyone can ask) and answers (which should be answered by those with a decent amount of training)
